# Compiler Error when passing an array as a param in VC++ 2010

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, compiler-errors, quicksort

This is possibly a newbie question, as I am just learning programming. I am learning about QuickSort algos, and I'm trying to pass an int array as a parameter to my function quickSort(). When I try to compile in VC++ 2010, I'm getting a compiler error.

I've looked up how to pass arrays as parameters, and tried to mirror what they did, but it didn't seem to work. here: [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) is where I looked it up, it's the last section on the page (scroll all the way to the bottom). I've tried to pass the array as outlined in that article, but I still get a compile error. See code blurb (incomplete) below for example of both what I am doing and the compile error. Any suggestions?

```
int aTest[7] = {7, 5, 9, 3, 4, 8, 6};
int left = 0;
int right = 6; 
quickSort(aTest, left, right);   //this is line 16 referenced in the compiler error
void quickSort(int aTest[], int left, int right)

//main.cpp(16): error C2664: 'quickSort' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int [7]' to 'int'
//          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
```

Comment: Don't take a reference from any website telling you to #define constants.

Comment: I didn't even realize it recommended that. I knew better than to do that though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i understand, this is C, not C++.
If i understand right, you should put the prototype before the "line 16".
By prototype, i mean the line `void quickSort(int aTest[], int left, int right)`.

Comment: When I changed it so that the quickSort() definition was above main(), that seemed to fix it. What was wrong with my forward declaration though, why was it only expecting an int?

Comment: @Empire: You may be using a C++ compiler, but you are programming in C.

Comment: I am? I wasn't aware that I knew C :). Can you tell me where I went wrong so that I can change this from C to C++? Everything I've been studying, all of the info I've gotten, was from C++ tutorials, so I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: @TheEmpire: With a C++ compiler, the error should tell you that the function has not been declared on line 16. But then a C compiler should accept it and perhaps complain that the declaration of quickSort when it gets to it has a different signature than expected (undeclared functions are assumed to return int).

Comment: Strange. I wish I had the original code to post above to see where I went wrong. I just tried to replicate it by writing a new program the same way I wrote the first, and no compile errors. So I guess it wasn't the "Same" way :) Thanks for everyone's help. First post here, and already I really like the community.

Answer (score 1):

As anatolyg states it's the prototype order.  The compiler assuming that quicksort takes a single int parameter.  Try setting the highest warning level and you should see a warning that quicksort is not defined.